# Android Bottom Navigation Bar Colors Show Lighter

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml

### The colors in the Bottom Navigation Bar show lighter than selected.

I wish to implement the tab bar as shown in the image below.

[image]

The selected tab will be highlighted as shown.

I am using the library `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`

However on implementation I am, getting the output as such with the colors much lighter than what I have added.
[image]

Here is my code in XML

> ```
>   android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
>     android:background="@drawable/bottom_navigation_background"
>     android:elevation="8dp"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_color_selector"
>     app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
>     app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
> ```

here is the color selector file

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:color="@color/white" />
    <item
        android:color="@color/light_black_40"/>
</selector>
```

Here is the color file

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#E63D4D</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#EF816F</color>

    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>

    <color name="light_black_40">#66000000</color>
    <color name="yellow">#FFF676</color>
</resources>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You :)

Comment: did you test it on other mobiles?

Comment: Yes, It is the same. It shows as such in the preview itself